# Existence of a holomorphic function on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, interpolation, banach-algebras, holomorphic-functions

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be two distinct points in the unit sphere of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., $z_1 \neq z_2$ and $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$.

I'd like to construct the bounded uniformly continuous holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ ($\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk of $\mathbb{C}$) satisfying:

(1) $\| f \|_{\mathbb{D}}=\sup\{|f(z)|:|z| < 1\} \leq 1$,

(2) $f(z_1)=0$ and $f(z_2)=1$.

I think there exists such a holomorphic function but I couldn't construct that one.

Comment: If your domain of $f$ is open unit disk, $f(z_1)$ and $f(z_2)$ should be undefined.

Comment: The problem is not well stated. As edm said, what sense do $f(z_1),f(z_2)$ make? Also note that (2) is redundant as you assumed $f(\mathbb D)\subset \mathbb D.$

Comment: I edited my question. However, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, we can extend the function $f$ to $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Here $f(z_1)$ and $f(z_2)$ are the values of the extension of $f$ at $z_1$ and $z_2$, respectively.

Comment: It may be helpful to try the form $f(z)=\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}(z-z_2+1)e^{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)g(z)}$. The remaining thing is to find a suitable holomorphic function $g(z)$ such that $(1)$ holds.

Comment: @EricYau If the norm of g on the unit disk is sufficiently small, then is it valid? How about the uniform convergence?